# Opencart 4 create child theme

Tags: opencart

I have not used Opencart in a while and I am looking to create a child theme of the default Opencart 4 default theme. My goal is that then when there is an update to the platform my customizations of the .tpl etc files won't get overwritten.

Most of the tutorials I am seeing are old and talk about creating a folder in a catalog/view/theme folder however in v4 it seems the folder structure is different.
Can anyone point me to a more recent tutorial for creating a child theme of the default oc4 theme

thanks